# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Tags: java, sql, oracle

i am trying to save value in database but i am getting this error

i tried this

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        captureScreen("img.jpg");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frontendUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("driver  loaded");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("driver not loaded");
    }

    String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String Username = "system";
    String Password = "toushif";
    try { 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,Username,Password);
        st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        String sql="insert into TOU3(file123) values('"+abc+"')";
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
    }                                        
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
}
```

Comment: What is `abc`? Can you post a complete example?

Comment: As a side note, you could consider using prepared statements to prevent severe vulnerabilities such as injection.

Comment: And what datatype is `tou3.file123`? Are you really doing this as `system` - it's not a good idea to have your own objects in the `system` or `sys` schemas...

Comment: It looks like maybe you're trying to store an image file into a `blob` field (I can only think you'd get that error with `blob` or `raw`), but you're actually inserting a string value into the field instead of the binary file contents? You'd have to use a prepared statement for that if so, and stream the data. Please clarify what you're doing and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    try { 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,Username,Password);
        st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        String sql="insert into TOU3(file123) values("+abc+")";
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
    }                                        
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That would work for a `number` column, though a prepared statement would still be better. But the error suggests the column is `raw` or `blob`. If it was `number` and the OP was just passing a quoted number there would be an implicit `to_number()` taking place, but it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are inserting string into BLOB type you need to use `getBytes()`

```
// ex:
String abc = "very long string";
// file123 is BLOB column
String query = "insert into TOU3(file123) values(" + abc.getBytes() + ")";
```